# Get a JSON return from a Overpass API call

Tags: json, overpass-api

From this call:

https://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?node[highway=speed_camera][bbox=-5.708215989569187,43.46669501043081,-5.605835010430813,43.588927989569186]

I'm trying to get a JSON return. Reading the API, I don't know where to put the [out:json]:

https://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?node[out:json][highway=speed_camera][bbox=-5.708215989569187,43.46669501043081,-5.605835010430813,43.588927989569186]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't get a JSON result from the [XAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/XAPI_Compatibility_Layer)-compatibility endpoint. Instead, use the standard Overpass API (“`interpreter`”) endpoint and put the `[out:json];` at the very start of your [ql query](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL):

```
https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node[highway=speed_camera](43.46669501043081,-5.708215989569187,43.588927989569186,-5.605835010430813);out%20meta;
```

(note the different ordering of the bbox coordinates compared to the xapi request!)