# Retrieving OpenStreetMap data (ways and its child nodes) by coordinates using Overpass API?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am new to using OSM.I am trying to download OSM data programmatically using Python. I need data of ways and its child nodes contained in a perimeter specified by coordinates. Currently, I am referring to https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper which is mighty useful, but I am facing issues with the APIs.

This does not give me any data. Not sure if it has to do with syntax.

```
data = api.get('way(42.819,-73.881,42.820,-73.880)')
```

When I try

```
MapQuery = overpass.MapQuery(50.746,7.154,50.748,7.157)
response = api.get(MapQuery)
```

I get a list of of features where I can't tell which is way or node.

I can work with XML or CSV format. I was hoping the data would look like a .osm file downloaded from JOSM.

Comment: overpass api with ways and your bounding box > http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Gb6 (hit run)

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks, now I am getting data. Problem now is, when I run this on PyCharm my data looks like 
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [-73.8805813, 42.8190013], "type": "Point"}, "id": 42001224, "properties": {"highway": "stop", "name": "All-way stop"}, "type": "Feature"},
I can work with xml or json, but the data is not in a template, like in overpass turbo, where I can identify way, node, nd.

Comment: see > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180568/get-a-json-return-from-a-overpass-api-call